# C# ASP.NET MVC - Download XML to Browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using ASP.NET 4.6 MVC. I'm saving an xml file as a byte array in my SQL db. I want to allow my user to download the file from the browser. I'm not getting any errors and no file is getting downloaded. I know there are plenty of these issues out there but I haven't seen one where a file isn't being downloaded (not even a corrupted one).

```
public ActionResult DownloadScript(int id) {
    try {
        var script = _db.PortalScripts.FirstOrDefault(i = >i.Id == id);
        if (script != null) {
            return File(script.ScriptBytes, "text/xml", script.Name);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        FlashMessage.Danger("Error downloading script");
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Scripts");
}
```

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadScript(HttpPostedFileBase file) {
        try {
            if (file.ContentLength > 0) {
                var newScript = new PortalScript {
                    Name = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName),
                    Version = "190.161",
                    Description = "This is a placeholder",
                    Displayed = true
                };

                using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
                    file.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
                    newScript.ScriptBytes = ms.ToArray();
                }

                var existingScripts = _db.PortalScripts.FirstOrDefault(s = >s.ScriptBytes == newScript.ScriptBytes);

                if (existingScripts == null) {
                    _db.PortalScripts.AddOrUpdate(newScript);
                    _db.SaveChanges();
                    FlashMessage.Confirmation(newScript.Name + " successfully uploaded");
                }
                else FlashMessage.Warning(newScript.Name + " already exists. Duplicate upload ignored.");

            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            FlashMessage.Danger("Upload failed: " + ex.Message);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Scripts");
    }
```

In my download method, my script variable is returning a properly filled out model. Not going into the catch either. Just getting redirected back to my original view with no file. Any suggestions??

Comment: If you are being redirected to "Scripts" this suggests that `_db.PortalScripts.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == id)` is null. Have you tried inspecting that line with a debugger?

Comment: that script variable is being returned properly. I can see the object is filled out correctly in the debugger.

Comment: Hmm could your browser be blocking the download, by any chance?

Comment: Hmm, just some debug ideas: can the file be saved before it's returned? if so, can you open it?... 2. Have you tried to use `FileResult` as return type?

Comment: Figured it out! Needed to use FileContentResult instead of FileResult and everything started working!